# How to connect ROS to a MQTT broker

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm totally new to ROS, and I want ROS to communicate  with a MQTT broker through the tcp protocol.
I have seen the TCPROS package but it needs the md5 sum which i don't have.
Is it possible to use TCPROS without md5 sum? How to do it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202922/how-to-connect-ros-to-a-mqtt-broker/) by [anhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21614/anhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-21**:
Have you solved your issue?

**Comment by [Meet H Thakkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/24239/meet-h-thakkar/) on 2015-10-06**:
is there a project already begin worked-out ? I would like to write this package/ process. Or contribute to it.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-10-06**:
Please don't add answers that are not answers; it is preferred to ask a new question. I found [this ros-users](http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20150313.122108.5c182bb8.en.html) that discusses [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/iot_bridge). Perhaps it is worth looking into.

**Comment by [godfreap](https://answers.ros.org/users/24928/godfreap/) on 2015-10-27**:
I'm new to ROS, but I have written a rospy script that changes messages from MQTT to ROS and vice versa. I have a few problems with it (mostly related to services being dumb and unable to send ROS images over them), but will post it once I find out how (just joined the site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They will not talk directly. They use different protocols. You will need to write a process which translates ROS messages in to MQTT compatible messages and resends them, as well as vice versa.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS `Kinetic` a package called [mqtt_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/mqtt_bridge) is available. At the time it's only sparsely documented so you might want to look into the [api doc](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/mqtt_bridge/html/annotated.html) or code itself, but from quick look it looks like you just pass a topic name for ROStoMQ conversion and the package internally serializes, and vice versa.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2